# Alfresco activiti workflow

Tags: alfresco, activiti

Is it possible to view an already filled form in a review step ? I have created a simple workflow, where the process starts with the user filling in a form. The filled form gets assigned to another user(lets call the user ABC) for reviewing. Is it possible for ABC to view the form filled by the user ? I am using the kickstart app to create a business process model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to assign a prefilled form for review to next stage in workflow process, you can use the form field called "Display Value". 
Add the 'Display value' from the form field options. Press 'Pencil' icon to update the display value.
From the dropdown list, select the form field values that is to be displayed in the review form.
[Display Value Activiti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkinG.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to copy the variables from the task with "fill form", to the task with the "review form", via the workflow Executioncontext. The var names in activiti (my_property) are then mapped to the var names in the alfresco content model/share forms (my:property) (but by substituting the ":" sign to a "_" sign).

You can do the copying of vars between tasks using TaskListeners in your bpmn2.0 file. See more here http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/wf-process-def-listeners.html

The gui from Activiti kickstart (AFAIK) is too limited to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks Stefan !! Will use TaskListeners. Hope it works for me

Comment: Hi Stefan !! Do you have any example that can help me implement this ? Alfresco docs aren't that helpful as I am very new to alfresco.